# Is it possible to create a derived table with no rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In other words, I can say this:

```
MERGE MyTable AS trg
USING (VALUES(1, 'a')) AS src(key, val)
ON ...
```

I want to be able to say this too:

```
-- does not work:
MERGE MyTable AS trg
USING () AS SRC(key, val)
ON ...
```

Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to find much official documentation on derived tables (Sql Server 2008R2) beyond the tangential references in the documentation for MERGE, FROM, etc.

Comment: What good would that be? If you have no source data to merge.... then why even merge???

Comment: The MERGE statement is generated in code. If the source data is empty, then the statement will delete the rows in the target table. (e.g. ... WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE ...)

Comment: `USING (SELECT 1 as 'key', 1 as 'val' where 1 = 0) AS src (key, val)` should do it, but I'm not sure how it would help you.

Comment: @Pondlife, that solves my problem.. thanks (if you answer I will accept :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using a query that can never return any rows as the derived table:

```
USING (SELECT 1 as 'key', 1 as 'val' where 1 = 0) AS src (key, val)
```

Comment: Thanks. Slightly simpler: USING (SELECT NULL, NULL WHERE 1=2) AS SRC(key, val)

Comment: @ChrisHerring Yes, that's perfect for your specific case; if anyone ever needs an empty derived table with column names then they can specify the names as I did.